# invoke tinymce preview from outside

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have TinMCE installed and now I would like to invoke the preview functionality from outside the editor. I mean when another preview button in clicked, it needs to invoke the tinymce preview so that I can see the preview popup. This is possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to follow this [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/axdaab/3)

Create a button outside editor.
Invoke this command onclick of this button.

```
 tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mcePreview');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a syntax like that for grab the content:

```
var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Or for the preview:

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().execCommand('mcePreview');
```